# Angular Form Builder - set value based on chosen select value property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

Here is my Angular Form Builder initialisation group:

```
    contactReason: this.formBuilder.group({
        description: '',
        source: this.sourceType()
    })
```

I have a select with predefined values for 'description' these can be many different values e.g. "request for information" Here is a mapping sample used elsewhere in my application:

```
public ContactReason = {
    "request for information": 'incoming',
    "other incoming": 'incoming',
    "call update": 'outgoing',
    "information provided": 'outgoing',
    "attempted contact": 'outgoing',
    "regular contact": 'outgoing',
    "other outgoing": 'outgoing',
};
```

As you can see each description is assigned to either "incoming or outgoing".

I want to create a method to do this mapping so when they select the description it will map "incoming or outgoing" here...

```
source: this.sourceType()

private sourceType() {
//logic for source mapping based on description.value
}
```

Any help with the above method would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Better way not to make the key-value pair complex. You can have an array as value like `public ContactReason = { incoming: ['a','b','c'], outgoing:['d','e','f']}`. This is the good practice where not to use value to find key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it mapped by the way I asked the question, by using the array of mapped values. Fairly straight forward but will leave up for reference.

```
public logEntryContactReason = {
        "request for information": 'incoming',
        "other incoming": 'incoming',
        "case update": 'outgoing',
        "information provided": 'outgoing',
        "attempted contact": 'outgoing',
        "regular contact": 'outgoing',
        "other outgoing": 'outgoing',
    };

private sourceType() {
    const data = this.contactForm.value;
   return this.logEntryContactReason[data.contactReason.description]
}
```